# How does Facebook keep that toolbar on the bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, toolbar

I like how [Facebook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook) keeps that toolbar on the bottom of the page.

Does that require cross-browser ninja skills?

Their [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)/[CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) files are huge so I am having a hard time narrowing down the implementation (for learning purposes).

Comment: You mean, how do they position it to the bottom of the window, or how do they make it stay there through multiple page requests?

Comment: how do they position it on the bottom of the page.  I didn't realize it doesn't reload when you go to another page?

Comment: It doesn't, for the most part.  They use ajax trickery for that part of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve the effect [with CSS](http://limpid.nl/lab/css/fixed/footer).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a basic example.  No, it doesn't require cross-browser ninja skillz. =)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Bar</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
}
#page {
margin: 10px;
overflow: auto;
height: 93%;
}
#bottom {
width: 100%;
background: #18f8f8;
text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
    Other stuff on page
</div>
<div id="bottom">Bottom stuff goes here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is that how they implemented it exactly? (at a high level ofcourse)

Answer (score 1):

The best is to install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and see how they did it. When I see interesting things on the web, Firebug is the best way to analyze it's HTML structure, attached CSS and you can even directly modify the CSS/HTML structure to see how it changes. Everything you see on a website can be simply read. Remember, the source (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) gets delivered with it :)

Answer (score 0):

That solution doesn't work well for pages that have content extending beyond the bottom of the browser window.

Try something like this instead:

```
<div style="display: block;
position: fixed;
text-align: center;
    z-index:1000;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
color: #999999;
clear: both;
height: 15px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-top-color: #b5b6b5;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
border-right-style: solid;
border-left-style: solid;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-right-color: #b5b6b5;
border-left-color: #b5b6b5;
background-color: #e7e7e7;"></div>
```

Comment: Looks like your code got eaten. Use the "code" button (1010) to wrap it so it doesn't vanish.